# Грамматическая основа сложного предложения

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее

В этом предложении четыре грамматические основы:

> Юридически данное положение неукоснительно выполняется, но жизнь вносит свои коррективы, и молодой следователь неспособен руководить человеком, проработавшим в розыске четверть века, как бы этого ему ни хотелось.

Хотела спросить по поводу 2, 3, 4.

**Вторая** - *жизнь вносит* или *жизнь вносит коррективы*?

**Третья** - *следователь неспособен* или *следователь неспособен руководить*? (склоняюсь ко второму варианту)

**Четвертая** - *ни хотелось* или *ему ни хотелось*? (склоняюсь к первому варианту)

Answer (score 5):

2. Жизнь вносит коррективы - глагольный фразеологизм (вносить коррективы =корректировать), простое глагольное сказуемое.
3. Следователь не способен руководить - СГС, раздельное написание НЕ.
4. Как ни хотелось, КАК НИ - союзное слово, односоставное предложение, сказуемое выражено безличной формой глагола.

Comment: Получается, что вносит коррективы  - простое глагольное сказуемое? *Прошу извинения за "не" - опечатка.

Answer (score 3):

Вторая основа: **жизнь вносит**. Я думаю, что глагол *вносить* может употребляться не только со словом *коррективы*, это разложимое сочетание. Третья основа: **следователь неспособен руководить**. Четвертая основа: **ни хотелось**.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

В третьей основе мы имеем СГС (сложное глагольное сказуемое), где слово *неспособен* играет роль вспомогательного слова, а инфинитив *руководить* передает основное значение.

В четвертей основе у нас безличное предложение. Здесь *ему* никак не может входить в состав сказуемого.